# Can we determine the fiber of a fiber bundle from the total space and the base space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let $F\hookrightarrow E \rightarrow B$ be a fiber bundle.
Assume we are only given $E$ and $B$, can we determine F?
The answer is clearly no: There is an infinite family of coverings
$$\mathbb{Z}/n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{S}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1.$$

However this example has some bad properties (at least from the point of algebraic topology): $\mathbb{S}^1$ is not simply connected (it is an $K(\mathbb{Z},1)$ though) and the fiber is not even connected.

Can we conclude something about $F$ if the base space $B$ is simply connected and/or if we know $F$ is connected, maybe if $B$ is a $K(G,n)$ for $n>1$ or if there are some manifolds involved?

There seem to be similar questions around here, but they always assumed knowledge of $F$ and $B$ or $F$ and $E$.

Edit: As from John Palmieris comment arise quite a lot of nice counterexamples let us further narrow down the spaces: What can we do, if $F$, $E$ and $B$ are homeomorphic to finite (finite dimensional) CW-spaces?

Comment: If you know that $E = F \times B$ and you know $E$ and $B$, can you figure out $F$? For example, consider $E=\mathbb{R}^\infty=B$.

Comment: Well if the projection map is a homotopy equivalence the fiber must be homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: @JohnPalmieri Ok, this really seems to provide a large class of counterexamples, even if we assume all spaces involved to be compact, as we have for any space X an infinite family $X^n\hookrightarrow X^{\times\infty} \twoheadrightarrow X^{\times\infty}$.
I have therefore adjusted the question.

Comment: $K(G,n)$'s are rarely finite dimensional, though. If you want to have some finiteness assumption but still allow $K(G,n)$'s you can ask for spaces homotopy equivalent to locally finite CW complexes (which $K(G,n)$'s are if $G$ is finite). In fact if you allow $K(G,n)$'s then the answer is quite simple : take two finite abelian groups $G,H$ and two morphisms $f,g: G\to H$ with different kernels, and consider the associated fibrations $K(G,2) \to K(H,2)$ which will yield homotopy-inequivalent fibers (EDIT : they may not be fiber bundles, I thought you had asked about fibrations !)

Comment: By a fiber bundle you mean a locally trivial fibration? Why not just choose a trivialising chart on $B$ to get $F$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $E = S^3 \times S^2$ and $B = S^2$. Then the projection $p : S^3 \times S^2 \to S^2$ is a fiber bundle with fiber $F = S^3$. Let $h : S^3 \to S^2$ be the Hopf fibration which is a fiber bundle with fiber $S^1$. Then
$$b : S^3 \times S^2 \stackrel{proj}{\rightarrow}S^3 \stackrel{h}{\rightarrow} S^2$$
is a fiber bundle with fiber $F = S^1 \times S^2$.